# windows comp command in batch script: remove prompts

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, command-prompt, file-comparison

Every time I use the Windows `comp` command, a message containing:

```
Compare more files (Y/N) ?
```

is shown. Can I avoid it by typing `N` by default?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also consider using another, also built-in, command, `FC`. It can perform binary comparison (you need to specify the `/B` switch: `FC /B file1 file2`), which seems closer to what `COMP` does, although the results are still displayed in a different format.

Anyway, it doesn't prompt you for more files to compare, it just does the job and terminates.

Answer (score 11):

You can pipe an N in there:

```
echo N | comp file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: +1 - It will still show the `Compare more files (Y/N)?` prompt, but it will also be answered with 'N'.